# Microsoft Excel connect to HANA Using MDX

Tags: excel, connection, mdx, hana

In the past I could connect Microsoft Excel to SAP HANA using MDX:

DATA → From Other Sources → From Data Connection Wizard → Other / Advanced → ... 
For more details view: [How To Integrate Hana Database with Excel](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/12/how-to-integrate-hana-database-with-excel/)

But this menu is not available any more (Excel for Office 365 MSO 16.0.11425.20242 - 64 Bit).

Even though the HANA Client ist installed.

So how to create a MDX Connection using Excel for Office 365?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MS Excel 356 at hand, but looking at the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/change-the-source-data-for-a-pivottable-afd93524-f7de-432c-84d0-3896fbbc2577) it looks as if in order to get external data **PivotTables** are the way to go.